# javascript focus() not working, nor setting field value

Tags: javascript, lotus-domino

Notes Domino web form, validating onblur what was entered in a field.   Field is set as a number but I want to catch what was entered immediately if it is not a number.   Then I want to clear what was entered and put the focus right back in the field.    I get the code to run, and the alert comes up correctly but the focus does not happen, nor does the value get removed.

```
function checkNumeric(fld, nm) {
    debugger;
      var x;
      x = document.getElementById(fld).value;
      // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
      if (isNaN(x)) {       
        document.getElementById(fld).value = '';
        alert("Non-numeric entry of '" + x + "' in : " + nm +", please try again.");
        document.getElementById(fld).focus();
      }       
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure fld is a string containing the id of the element? Give the console.log of fld, please

Comment: Lotos is old. Instead of using the ID use the doument.form and the name of the input field. The code itself looks correct. IF FLD and NM arer really strings ( check with typeof ). And as a tip. you can save a bit typing and computing time if you put the input element in a variable. You calculates them 3 times :)

Comment: Notes is not old, but that's irrelevant. Could it be that the focus works, but there is another focus afterwards? For example, do you test all fields, and you stop at the first error? Maybe a return true or false will help you in the calling function, to stop evaluating fields.

Answer (score 1):

Be also sure that the event handler which calls this is set to prevent default. Otherwise it might be the element get the focus but is removed afterwards by the event handler emediatly.

```
            function checkNumeric(fld, nm) {
            //debugger;
            var x;
            if (typeof fld !== "string") {
                alert("fld is not a string");
            }
            if (typeof nm !== "string") {
                alert("nm is not a string");
            }

            var elm = document.getElementById(fld);
            if (elm) {
                x = elm.value;
                if (isNaN(x)) {
                    elm.value = '';
                    alert("Non-numeric entry of '" + x + "' in : " + nm + ", please try again.");
                    elm.focus();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am now using this last code that Thomas provided, and it is not giving an alert of fld or nm not being a string, and it recognizes the element, as I have it clearing the non-numeric value now.  The only issue is the focus, and i am not sure how to do what he suggested, as I am not using a custom built event handler, just using the on-blur property of the field.    I can live with this, but it is bugging me that I can't get the cursor back in the field, to force them to try again.

Comment: Matt i was often wondering why things do not act as they should. Usuall later figured out it was just a side effect in the event handling. I would write some test code to figure out if the blur thing is really working in your enviroenment. If its like that i would use a chrome browser or firefox to trace the event handling. You doesnt provides enough source to check it . I have the "feel" that something happens outside your code which activates another field so your field looses the focus immediatly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Thomas.  Unfortunately, as things go, I have so many things going on I have not been able to get back to this, but I know I have not resolved it.   I will take your suggestion and post anything I can share here.